# Added Gson to the pom.xml but is not found

Tags: java, xml, maven, gson

I have added **gson** to my **pom.xml**. Here is it. But when I call `Gson gson = new Gson()` and try so search in maven repository it doesn't found any element. Why? Where do I wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>VolaConNoi_webapp</artifactId>
    <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
    <artifactId>VolaConNoi_webapp-ear</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>VolaConNoi_webapp-ear</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
            <artifactId>VolaConNoi_webapp-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.volaconnoi</groupId>
            <artifactId>VolaConNoi_webapp-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.4</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

EDIT

[image]

Comment: did you import the Gson library? And which ide are you using?

Comment: you mean in the java file I have to write import com.google etc...?

Comment: what does mean "is not found"? do you receive a Maven error? in this case, show us this error.

Comment: for it to be found in the maven repository you should run maven clean install first time when you add a new library to you pom file

Comment: I'm working on netbeans. In my java file I write Gson gson = new Gson(). then I click to the right in "Search dependencies in Maven repository..." but when the dialog window open it show me "No matching result"

Comment: Yes you still need to `import` the library, maven just downloads the dependency for you

Comment: execute `mvn clean install` in a terminal in your project folder and show us the output.

Comment: from my terminal the mvn command is not found...I suppose I should add it to my classpath. I'm using the maven version bundled with netbeans

Comment: Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: I have excecuted mvn inside my EAR project folder and I get build success. the gson jar is now under the dependencies directory but I still get errors

Comment: I posted a screenshot

Comment: I fixed the problem finally. I added the gson under the EAR dependencies folder. Instead since I use it in a servlet that is placed under WAR project when I added it gson under dependencies folder of wAR project it worked

Answer (score 6):

Kindly add this to your **pom.xml** file under **project** This would tell maven to download the libraries you include in the pom file from here:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

And your code will be something like this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

And [consult this guide on how to use Gson](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/) in case you need help using it too.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP but in Eclipse. This works but I just can't get any auto-completion. Can this be related to Gson itself?

Comment: Struggled with this for a few hours until I found this post.  I know it's a couple of years old but it still applies, at least to some Eclipse distributions.